# HTTPS Certificate issues

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

When I access my deployed site by making use of: https://theDomain.com everything works as well as the certificate associated with the wildcard domain. But when I access it through https://www.theDomain.com, I get an unsecure message, stating that the certificate is not valid for the domain. The site is running on azure.

What I don't understand is why the www makes a difference. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

As requested, the following url as well as the certificate works fine: https://briteplan.com, but when you change it to https://www.briteplan.com it doesn't work. The certificate is a wildcard for *briteplan.com

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to say from the current information but one reason might b that the certificate for the domain is not valid for www.domain. These are different names and should be either both contained in the same certificate or you need to have multiple certificates and send the matching certificate.
Another reason might be that domain and www.domain are actually setup in the DNS to point to different IP addresses. In this case there are probably different servers with a different setup (including different certificates) for domain and www.domain.
More information can be given if you include the problematic domain in your question so that one can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Many thanks for the response, I'll update my question

Comment: @RichardBailey: after looking at the details of the setup my guess is that you've enabled the certificate only for domain but not for www.domain in azure. Because of this it is returning the default certificate of azure.

Comment: many thanks for the information. Now at least I have a point to start looking what's wrong. Many thanks